# netbeans 8.1 cannot create new project of uninstall from windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have installed java 8.1 and netbeans 8.1 on my windows 10 pc and am having some problems:

1. I cannot create a new project in netbeans.  When I attempt to
   create a new project the netbeans application shuts down.
2. I cannot uninstall the netbeans application; it starts with the
   message that it is configuring the installer then shuts down.

I have been able to uninstall java on my pc and reinstall without error.  I don't know what steps to try from here.  Any help greatly appreciated.

ERROR LOG:
...
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6f3321f4,
pid=7052, tid=0x0000141c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build
1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode, sharing
windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x121f4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
...

Comment: delete netbeans folder from you C:\Program Files\Netbeans , C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME
then try to uninstall and install

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no luck.

Comment: did you delete other netbeans config file check C:\Users\pankaj\AppData location it have three folder delete all netbeans file also and then uninstall and install again

Comment: try to install latest version of netbeans

Comment: I am running java jdk 1.8 ... can the newest version of netbeans use that older version of java?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the error log that gets written on an attempt to install netbeans.

Comment: Similar crashes have been reported, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8179014 -- should be fixed in jdk 8 141 or jdk 9

Comment: The answer is:  there is a problem with my user account on windows.  I created a new user account and netbeans installed and works without a problem.  Thanks to all who have helped with this question.